# Should a table which holds only status information be in a 0 to 1 relationship with entity tables

Tags: database-design, foreign-keys, relational-database

Is it correct to say that if you have a table made up of orders like so:

`ID - int`

`Item - nvarchar(50)`

`OrderStatus - int`

And and order status table like so

`ID - int`

`Status - nvarchar(100)`

Assuming all fields are not nullable. Every order must have one Order Status ID, but the order status table doesn't need to know anything about the order table. Would this be a 0 to 1 relationship, with the 1 being on the order table and 0 on the order status?

To me it seems like it should be, but I may just have the notion of this relationship all wrong.

Comment: From your description it seems like a "one to many" or "zero/one to many" relationship: Every order has one status and therefore each status may have zero, one or more orders associated with it.

Comment: @sqlvogel Thanks, I hadn't thought of it that way.So despite the order status table not holding a direct reference to any orders, if any orders reference it, it makes it a 1 - 0/* relationship.

Comment: Chibbles, Correct. What you have described usually is the case in a relational or SQL database. It's not normally possible to have a "direct" reference (such as a foreign key) on the "one" side of the relationship. What made you think this was an exceptional case?

Comment: @sqlvogel I didn't think it was an exceptional case, it's the fact that my knowledge of relationship types isn't complete. But this is another piece of the puzzle in place. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

How many statuses does each order have, and how many orders does each order status have? If the answers to these questions are "one" and "one" then what you probably want is a single table.

Comment: Each order has one status. The status is stored in the order table as an integer. This integer is a foreign key to the ID of the orderstatus table. The "Status" field hold the text of that particular status. So the orderstatus has no order associated to it. It is only used to lookup a status based on its ID.

Comment: OK, so each meaningful status value is associated with multiple orders -- the separate table is the correct approach.